# When is the phase shift small and linear in $k$ for low energy $s$-wave scattering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, scattering

I was wondering when should we expect the phase shift to be small and linear in $k$ for low energy $s$-wave scattering, so that the scattering length can defined as $-\delta/k$, since the general form of the scattering length for low energy is $-\tan(\delta)/k$, the two only seem to be equal to each other when the phase shift is small or close to zero. Also will a scattering length that is equal to $-\delta/k$ always be finite and not approach infinity like $-\tan(\delta)/k$ would when $\delta=\pi/2$.